# Python panel source code

Tags: panel, source-code

I saw a tutorial where the guy right clicked on any object in the GUI (he chose Transform->Translate) and he got the Python source code for that panel with an indicator for the line where the operator is. That quite a neat trick. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I use Blender 2.9 and the video was from 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable *"Developper Extras"* in the preferences, so that you can *"Edit source"*.

[image]